# Separação de bytes

Tags: java

Estou construindo um sistema para fazer comunicação via Socket:

O sistema cliente envia as seguintes informações:

**1 - int - tamanho da mensagem**

**2 - bytes - a mensagem**

A mensagem é constituída por:

**1 - int - código do método que quero executar no servidor**

**2 - int - tamanho da lista que quero enviar**

**3 - int - id da pessoa**

**4 - int - tamanho da string do nome da pessoa**

**5 - String - string do nome da pessoa**

Os tópicos 3, 4 e 5 são executados para cada item da lista

Meu sistema cliente fica assim:

```
private void btComunicarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        List<PessoaMOD> pessoas = new ArrayList<PessoaMOD>();
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(1, "Pessoa 1"));
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(2, "Pessoa 2"));
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(3, "Pessoa 3"));
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(4, "Pessoa 4"));
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(5, "Pessoa 5"));
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(6, "Pessoa 6"));
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(7, "Pessoa 7"));
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(8, "Pessoa 8"));
        try {
            Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            enviarMensagem(codificarListarPessoas(pessoas), cliente);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
        }
    }                                           

    public ByteArrayOutputStream codificarListarPessoas(List<PessoaMOD> pessoas) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        dos.writeByte(1); //Método 1, gravar pessoas 
        dos.writeInt(pessoas.size()); // tamanho da lista
        for (PessoaMOD p : pessoas) {
            dos.writeInt(p.getId()); // id da pessoa
            dos.writeInt(p.getNome().length()); //Nr de caracteres do nome da pessoa
            dos.writeChars(p.getNome()); //Nome da pessoa
        }
        return bos;
    }

    public void enviarMensagem(ByteArrayOutputStream mensagem, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        byte[] msg = mensagem.toByteArray();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeInt(msg.length); //O tamanho da mensagem
        out.write(msg); //Os dados
        out.flush();
    }
```

Minha dúvida é de ler isto no servidor:
Estou fazendo assim no servidor:

```
private void btIniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(12345);
                    System.out.println("Servidor ouvindo a porta 12345");
                    while (true) {
                        Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
                        System.out.println("Cliente conectado: " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                        DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

                        int tamanhoMsg = entrada.readInt(); // ler tamanho da mensagem

                        // leio os bytes de acordo com o 
                        //tamanho da mensagem lida anteriormente
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanhoMsg];
                        int op = entrada.read(bytes, 0 , bytes.length);                        

                        // Como posso fazer a leitura separada dos dados enviados?

                        entrada.close();
                        cliente.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Li o tamanho da mensagem e recebi todos os bytes de acordo com o tamanho enviado.....

Mas agora como posso separar esses bytes de acordo com os dados que enviei, ou seja, separar tamanho da lista, id, tamanho da string, string do nome.

Comment: Acredito que você precisa de mais informações sobre, por exemplo, tamanho dos números e codificação da String.

Comment: Então, pra que seria este "tamanho dos números"? Como posso desmembrar este meu bytes?

Comment: Na outra resposta você disse que você mesmo está enviando esses dados do outro lado. Nesse caso, por que está usando dados binários crus? Por que não usa serialização?

Comment: Para usar serialização eu teria que usar o ObjectInputStream e o ObjectOutputStream, e li em vários tutoriais que não é recomendado usar essas classes e nem enviar por serialização. E enviando um objeto, por exemplo, uma List<PessoaMOD>, o nome dos pacotes da classe PessoaMOD teriam que ser iguais na aplicação cliente e servidor. eu pensei em converter meu objeto para JSON e enviar como String, e do outro lado fazer o processo inverso, será que é viável?

Comment: É preciso que você entenda os argumentos usados por quem falou que não se deve usar ObjectOutputStream em vez de seguir cegamente. Se houver problemas mesmo que possam afetar a sua aplicação, ainda assim você pode optar por transferir seus dados usando uma representação de dados comum, como JSON ou XML. Vai facilitar muito a sua vida, especialmente quanto a dados mal-formatados.

Comment: Entendi, se eu enviar como JSON a transmissão não fica lenta? Ou se a String for muito grande, não pode ocorrer perda de dados?

Comment: "Otimização prematura é a raiz de todos os males" :)
Preocupe-se primeiro em escrever o código mais limpo e simples que resolve o seu problema. Se houver lentidão, meça e verifique qual é a causa.

Comment: Ok, mas como eu disse, se a String do JSON for muito grande, não pode ocorrer perda de dados?

Comment: Os protocolos de rede garantem que isso não vai ocorrer sem aviso. Se ocorrer, você receberá um erro que poderá tratar. Mas não acredito que esses dados vão ficar muito grandes, de qualquer forma.

Comment: Vou fazer um teste com uma carga grande de um BD, qualquer coisa volto aqui. Vlw

Comment: Editei o tópico, há perda da String com JSON grande.

Comment: Certo. Pode abrir uma nova pergunta e colocar esse conteúdo lá? Assim conseguirá mais atenção e não desvirtuará o propósito dessa, tornando essa e a outra mais úteis para outros usuários também.

Comment: Já criei. Vlw pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Quer um conselho? Use JSON. Ficar criando protocolos binários é pedir para se incomodar. Amanhã ou depois você tem de interfacear com uma contraparte que não foi escrita em Java...

Comment: Então, meu receio é que usando JSON terei que ler byte a byte, isso não tornaria lento?

Comment: Não, você vai ler bloco a bloco, vai chamar read(buffer) onde o buffer pode ter milhares de bytes. O que você tem de fazer é ler um bloco, concatenar o que conseguiu ler num outro buffer que contenha os blocos já lidos, e verificar se já possui uma mensagem JSON completa. O único overhead que você tem é essa verificação. Na prática, normalmente read(buffer) vai receber o conteúdo de um pacote TCP, uns 1400 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Da mesma forma que você fez a escrita... agora você precisa fazer a leitura.
Basta seguir a mesma ordem.

Por exemplo, você colocou o tamanho com writeInt e leu com readInt.
Faça o mesmo pro restante (se você escreveu com writeChars, você deve ler com readChars e assim por diante).

Se quiser usar o vetor de bytes, você pode criar vetores de bytes temporários com o tamanho do objeto que quer converter e então:

```
String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int i= bytes[0];
```

Comment: Mas se eu fizer assim o "tamanho da mensagem" que passo primeiro de tudo não fará sentido, pois com base no tamanho da mensagem eu sei quantos bytes que vão ser enviados, então eu preciso pegar tudo de uma vez, eu já peguei tudo de uma vez com o:

    byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanhoMsg];
    int op = entrada.read(bytes, 0 , bytes.length);

Agora só preciso desmembrar estes bytes...

Comment: Depende do seu protocolo... Talvez criar um cabeçalho para a comunicação e no cabeçalho mandar informações de como desmembrar sua mensagem ou definir uma estrutura fixa e respeitar ela para cada tamanho de pacote.

Comment: Então, eu já mando o cabeçalho, eu envio o tamanho da mensagem, e para as strings envio o tamanho da string. Estou tendo dificuldade para desmembrar os bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Definindo um objetivo

A primeira coisa é entender o que você está fazendo. Basicamente você está criando um protocolo próprio. Esse protocolo define o formato no qual você está serializando uma mensagem e a rotina de desserialização deve respeitar meticulosamente o mesmo formato.

Trabalhar em nível de bytes é algo que pode exigir alguns conhecimentos mais avançados de como cada tipo complexo, por exemplo uma String, pode ser representado em bytes.

## Problemas da implementação atual

### Codificação de caracteres

O primeiro problema é que na geração da mensagem você está gravando os caracteres do nome de forma errada. O método `writeChars` não faz o que você pensa que ele faz. A String perderá informação.

Sempre que trabalhar com transformação de Strings você deve levar em conta que as Strings são representadas usando alguma codificação como `UTF-8`, `ASCII` ou `ISO--8859-1`. Além disso, nem sempre o número de bytes é igual ou proporcional ao número de caracteres.

No caso, a classe `DataOutputStream` possui o método `writeUTF` que é feito justamente para codificar corretamente Strings em `UTF-8`, incluindo ainda a informação da quantidade de bytes.

### Organização

Eu sei que este provavelmente é um exercício que não será usado num sistema de verdade. Porém, sempre organize seu código de forma que seja fácil testar partes isoladas.

O exemplo mais claro do problema é que não é possível testar a serialização e desserialização em bytes sem depender de rodar o programa inteiro e conectar os sockets.

Provavelmente você já deve ter executado isso algumas dezenas de vezes, talvez centenas e perde muito tempo apenas para fazer um teste simples. Para ser mais eficiente, basta extrair os trechos importantes em métodos e criar uma classe que execute somente esses trechos isolados.

Somente depois que a seralização estiver funcionando é que você deve se preocupar em fazer os sockets e outros aspectos do programa funcionarem.

## Solução

Fiz uma implementação simplificada do processo e vou colocar os trechos de código abaixo.

### Serialização

Isolei a serialização da lista de pessoas assim:

```
public static byte[] serializarPessoas(List<PessoaMOD> pessoas) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    dos.writeInt(pessoas.size()); // tamanho da lista
    for (PessoaMOD p : pessoas) {
        dos.writeInt(p.getId()); // id da pessoa
        dos.writeUTF(p.getNome()); //Nome da pessoa
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

### Desserialização

Para reconstruir os objetos a partir de um array de bytes ou mesmo de um `InputStream`, basta usar a classe `DataInputStream` e ler os bytes na exata ordem em que os escreve:

```
public static List<PessoaMOD> desserializarPessoas(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    List<PessoaMOD> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
    int quantidadePessoas = entrada.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidadePessoas; i++) {
        int id = entrada.readInt();
        String nome = entrada.readUTF();
        pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(id, nome));
    }
    return pessoas;
}
```

### Teste

Finalmente, criei um método para garantir que as implementações acima funcionam devidamente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<PessoaMOD> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(1, "Pessoa 1"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(2, "Pessoa 2"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(3, "Pessoa 3"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(4, "Pessoa 4"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(5, "Pessoa 5"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(6, "Pessoa 6"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(7, "Pessoa 7"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(8, "Pessoa 8"));

    byte[] bytes = serializarPessoas(pessoas);
    List<PessoaMOD> novasPessoas = desserializarPessoas(bytes);

    if (!pessoas.equals(novasPessoas)) {
        throw new IOException("O programa não conseguiu reconstruir os dados!");
    }
}
```

Adicionei o método `equals` na classe `PessoaMOD` para que a comparação da lista original com a versão restaurada funcione corretamente:

```
public class PessoaMOD {
    private String nome;
    private int id;
    public PessoaMOD(int id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PessoaMOD pessoaMOD = (PessoaMOD) o;
        return id == pessoaMOD.id &&
                Objects.equals(nome, pessoaMOD.nome);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(nome, id);
    }
}
```

## Alternativa usando Serialização

Outra alternativa ao invés de criar um protocolo próprio é encapsular a mensagem como no [padrão *Command*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

### Implementando uma `Mensagem` genérica

Para isso, precisamos de uma classe genérica para representar a mensagem, por exemplo:

```
public abstract class Mensagem implements Serializable {
    private Metodo metodo;
    private Object conteudo;
    public Mensagem(Metodo metodo, Object conteudo) {
        this.metodo = metodo;
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Mensagem that = (Mensagem) o;
        return metodo == that.metodo &&
                this.conteudo.equals(that.conteudo);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(metodo, conteudo);
    }
}
```

Note que ao invés de usar um inteiro, criei um Enum para representar o método a ser executado:

```
public enum Metodo {
    GRAVAR
}
```

### Criando a mensagem específica para esta ação

Então podemos criar a implementação para a mensagem de gravar as pessoas:

```
public static class MensagemGravarPessoa extends Mensagem {
    public MensagemGravarPessoa(List<PessoaMOD> pessoas) {
        super(Metodo.GRAVAR, pessoas);
    }
}
```

A classe `PessoaMOD` permanece a mesma.

### Serializando e desserializando

Os métodos de serialização e desserialização ficam muito mais simples ao usarmos o `ObjectOutputStream` e `ObjectInputStream` para fazer o trabalho pesado:

```
public static Mensagem desserializarPessoas(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    return (Mensagem) entrada.readObject();
}

public static byte[] serializarPessoas(Mensagem p) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    os.writeObject(p);
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

### Teste

Finalmente, a rotina de teste:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List<PessoaMOD> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(1, "Pessoa 1"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(2, "Pessoa 2"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(3, "Pessoa 3"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(4, "Pessoa 4"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(5, "Pessoa 5"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(6, "Pessoa 6"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(7, "Pessoa 7"));
    pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(8, "Pessoa 8"));

    Mensagem mensagem = new MensagemGravarPessoa(pessoas);

    byte[] bytes = serializarPessoas(mensagem);
    Mensagem mensagemNova = desserializarPessoas(bytes);

    if (!mensagem.equals(mensagemNova)) {
        throw new IOException("O programa não conseguiu reconstruir os dados!");
    }
}
```

Na verdade, dependendo da granularidade de classes do *Command pattern*, você nem precisaria do Enum para dizer o método.

Finalmente, quando você receber uma mensagem, basta usar o operador `instanceof` para verificar de que tipo é a mensagem. Exemplo:

```
if (mensagem instanceof MensagemGravarPessoa) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Vlw pela resposta cara, me ajudou bastante com os exemplos. Só que ainda acontece um problema... Caso os dados enviados sejam muito grandes quando faço isso: "out.writeInt(mensagem.length); //O tamanho da mensagem", avariável "lenght" é int, se a mensagem for muito grande não pegará o real tamanho da mensagem pois estoura o maximo suportado por int. Ai no servidor faço assim: "int tamanhoMsg = entrada.readInt(); byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanhoMsg]; entrada.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);" Com isso não pegará todos os dados.

Comment: @RodrigoLima Se você tem mensagens muito longas, você pode trocar o `int` por `long`. Entretanto, não recomendaria transmitir mensagens muito longas dessa forma, pois facilmente pode haver alguma perda de dados. Casos complexos demandam soluções mais complexas. Isso é acadêmico ou você pretende usar isso num sistema de verdade?